# How to Upload file onclick of button of type=button not type=submit in mvc4 using html begin form

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-4, button, upload, submit

I have to upload a file using a button (of type button, not submit).

And I want to show popup when no-file is selected and clicked on upload, it should not go to controller action.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: provide code that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home",new {@id="frm"}))
{
    <input type="file" id="upld" />
    <input type="button" value="upload" id="btn" />
}

<script>
  $('#btn').click(function(){
     var has_selected_file = $('#upld').filter(function(){
          return $.trim(this.value) != ''
     }).length  > 0 ; 
     if(has_selected_file){
          $('#frm').submit();
      }
      else{
          alert('No file selected');
      }
  });
```

I hope this is your requirement

Comment: Thanks.. This is what my requirement is... Thanks for spending some time for my question. cheers :)